# What the difference between a code review and a code audit?

Tags: terminology

According to Wikipedia:

> A software code audit is a comprehensive analysis of source code in a programming project with the intent of discovering bugs, security breaches or violations of programming conventions.

Source: [Code audit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_audit&oldid=616668852)

> Code review is systematic examination (sometimes referred to as peer review) of computer source code. It is intended to find mistakes overlooked in the initial development phase, improving the overall quality of software.

Source: [Code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_review&oldid=694368231)

I can't see the difference here. Could somebody please pin-point the difference between code review vs. code audit?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, A code audit involves the whole software, a code review focuses only on a part of it and may be included in the workflow to add code to your software (via pull/merge requests).

Answer (score 2):

They are different in `when` and `how big`.

`When`

- `Code reviews` are performed in 2 typical cases. First, a `Pull Request` coming, then the maintainer must do a `code review` for that PR. Second, to enhance the coding ability of team, we perform mutual `code review` once or twice per week.
- `Code audit` is performed in 2 typical cases. Given I am your customer or QA/QC department in your company. In the first case, I want to assure your source code complying with the standards of ISO or PEP or alike. In the second case, I doubt that something seriously bad happening in the code. Either the case, I request you to perform a `code audit`.

`How big`

- `Code reviews` are performed with bit-sized files.
- `Code audit` is performed in the whole project aspect: Architecture, Infra, Scaling, Docs, Clean code...

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes Code Reviews are performed before code is checked in or merged with the main branch, and Code Audits are typically performed afterwards.